# Regex of plus sign and spaces

Tags: regex

I need to replace **'+'** and **' ' (space)** signs in my string with **''**; Have RegExp for spaces > **/\s/g**, need to add **'+'** symbol to this. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically want to replace spaces, you can just use a literal space in your regex pattern. `\s` is a character class that matches all whitespace characters (newline, carriage return, tab, etc).

To match both spaces and plus signs, you can create a character set with square brackets:

`/[ +]/g`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Lx2U2G/1